# Ctrl Alt Delete on RDP with Macbook installed windows 7

Tags: remote-desktop, macbook

I have Macbook with Windows 7 installed
and connected to Windows 2012 server with Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection.
How can I run Ctrl + Alt + Delete on Windows 2012 Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Standard windows RDP is Ctrl+Alt+End, do mac books have this key?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I found it, it was:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>right-arrow</kbd>

Comment: It is Ctrl-Alt-End - regardless of what OS you are running on the client.

Comment: there is no End button on Mac

Comment: Yes, there is. It is a virtual key that you can achieve by pressing the physical keys: Fn and right arrow.

Comment: This is the correct answer, the other answer doesn't work as stated in the comments

Comment: My issue was that I log into the MACBook, VPN into corporate, RDP to my office PC, VPN into the production environment, RDP to the machine that I needed to send Ctrl-Alt-Del to. But it kept going to the middle machine, not the third in the chain. THIS solution got it where I needed it. Thanks.

Answer (score 65):

This is what worked for me on my Macbook Pro using Yosemite (10.10.2) and the [official RDP client from Microsoft](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-remote-desktop/id715768417) while connected to a Windows 2012R2 server:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

Comment: this sends CTRL+ALT+DEL to the local machine not the remote machine

Comment: @MatthewLock it should send it to the remote machine in full screen mode

Comment: fn + control + option + delete - works for me on my MacBook 16" 2019 using Microsofts Mac RDP client

Answer (score 15):

I cannot comment on other answers because of my "reputation points". What worked for me was slm but in this format:

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>

MAC keyboard.

Comment: This works for sending to Remote Desktop Connection on Mac OS. I was routed here while searching the key combination for this purpose.

Answer (score 6):

There is no <kbd>delete</kbd> button on my laptop keyboard, this works on my laptop: <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>backspace</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

for me, prior suggestions didn't work but provided some insight

what ended up working for me was

<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>right-arrow</kbd>

Comment: *prior suggestions didn't work* and yet this is an almost verbatim copy of a previous answer. If you don't have anything new or different to add then pleaser don't.

Comment: the **almost** answer didn't work for me, so I posted what did work

Comment: Yes, the value in this answer is that the other answers specify an "alt" key, and Macs don't have alt keys.

Answer (score 0):

What I find best to use the ease of access feature and enable the on-screen keyboard and then click ctrl+alt+del and it sends the command and allows me to type in the password, then just turn off the feature and close the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I am using citrix in MacBook. In citrix (windows 10) i'm running Remote Desktop (windows server 2014) <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>right-arrow</kbd> works perfect. 
Other options doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Following combination worked for me on MacOS Catalina ( 10.15.7 ) -  <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>delete</kbd>.

RDP OS was Windows 10.

The other combination with command and right arrow didn't worked for me.